# How to auto remove items from cart after 1 day - Magento 2.2.4

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.2.2, cookie, checkoutsession

Guest / Logged-in user:

- Auto removes items from the cart after 24 hours.
- Canceling and returning from the payment page auto-remove cart after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Custom module & Set Cron which will run after a certain interval of time.

In that you can use below code

```
<?php
namespace Company\Custom\Cron;

class Custom {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $itemCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $quoteCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quoteCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory $itemCollectionFactory,  
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository 
    ) {

        $this->quoteCollectionFactory = $quoteCollectionFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->itemCollectionFactory = $itemCollectionFactory;
    }
    public function getItemData()
    {   
        $fromTime = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimezone('UTC'));
        $toTime = clone $fromTime;
        $fromTime->sub(\DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minutes'));
        echo  $fromDate = $fromTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        echo $toDate = $toTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


        $itemColelction =$this->itemCollectionFactory->create()
              ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')
               ->addFieldToSelect('item_id')
               ->addFieldToSelect('quote_id')
               ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $fromDate]);     

        if($quoteCollection->getSize() >0){
            foreach ($itemColelction as $item)
            {
                $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($item->getQuoteId());
                $quote->deleteItem($item);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi how to use the above code ?

Comment: Create a custom module to run cron & from there call this function

Comment: set the value as 
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60*24);

otherwise set value as 86400 in your php.ini

/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom cronjob, please see my answer below.

**1. crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="remove_cart_items" instance="Your\Module\Cron\DeleteQuote" method="execute">
            <schedule>* */24 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**2. DeleteQuote.php**

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Cron;

use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DeleteQuote {

    protected $logger;

    protected $_quoteFactory;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quoteFactory,
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        try {
            $this->logger->info('Cron run of quote delete.');
            $collection = $this->_quoteFactory->create();
            $count = 0;

            foreach ($collection as $value) {
                if(count($value->getItemsCollection()->getData())){
                    foreach ($value->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
                        /*log which quote is deleted*/
                        $this->logger->info('Cron delete of stock delete '. $item->getId());
                        $item->delete();
                        $count++;
                    }
                }   
            }
            $this->logger->info('Total Deleted quotes'. $count);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info('Cron Error '. $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I done this, in a simple method.

set the value as

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24);

otherwise set value as 86400 in your php.ini

/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini
[image]

[image]